# Encrypted notes managing tool

Tags: note-taking, encryption

I keep all my notes in a single [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/) project. Notes are represented as simple `.md` files organized in directories.

I'd like to use some encryption tool that would allow me to stick to the same approach but save all those notes as encrypted file without any backdoors. Only password-based access.

Or maybe there are some alternative handy ways to manage notes?

Ideally, on OSX, iOS and Android.

Comment: What about a VeraCrypt volume to save all those files in?

Comment: @schroeder thank you! Looks like it is exactly what i'm looking for